# Using bind to reduce callback hell

Tags: node.js, callback, bind

I have lots of API data calls In the form of:

```
app.get('/getSomeData', function(req, res) {
  //get parameters
  dataService.getSomeData(param1, param2, commonCallback.bind(null, null, res));
});

var commonCallback = function (err, payload, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("server error ");
    res.status(500).end();
    return;
  }
  if (payload.messageType == 'errorMessage') {
    res.status(401).json(payload);
  } else {
    res.json(payload);
  }
}
```

and in DataService.js:

```
const getSomeData = function (param1, param2, callback) {
    //do some work
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return;
    }
    callback(null, payload);
}

exports.getSomeData = getSomeData;
```

but I get errors complaining that there are `Cannot read property 'json' of null`  I don't think I'm using bind() correctly.  But there doesn't seem to be many non-trivial examples out there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use promises to reduce callback hell, not `bind()`.

Comment: FYI, you call `callback(err)`, but your callback function NEEDs all three parameters, in particular it must have `res`.   And, your use of `bind()` is indeed, not correct.  This is really just not the way to do things.  If you were going to use `bind()`, I'd pass `res` as the first argument to `bind()` and then use `this` in place of `res`.  But, this is hack code.  Not a good way to do things.

Comment: What is your node.js version?